# Pyserial ImportError: No module named serial

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyserial

I'm  trying to use PySerial on Ubuntu, but it simply doesn't work. I have tried the following:

- Install serial
- Uninstall serial, install pyserial (yes, with pip3)
- sudo apt install python3-serial
- Restart(!)

and nothing works. Every time I get the same error (ImportError: No module named serial)

Comment: Can you paste some example or how you run the code?

Comment: I reinstalled everything and somehow it worked...